# Aggregate results, sum only if condition is true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get a sum of *all* values of `$revenue`, and a count of only where `$user` is equal to the user param I pass when calling this function.

```
this.aggregate([
    { $match: { createdAt: { $gte: start, $lte: end }, 'status.verified': true } },
    { 
      $group: { 
        _id: null,
        balance: {
          $sum: "$revenue"
        },
        count: {
          $cond: { 
            if: { $eq: [ "$user", user ] }, 
            then: { $sum: 1 },
            else: { $sum: 0 }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ], next);
```

I'm expecting the data to look like this:

```
[ { _id: null, balance: 1287, count: 10 ] }
```

Where balance is the sum of all revenue fields in the match query, and count is the count of that users contributions to the data.

It works fine if I sum the count unconditionally (e.g. like this)

```
this.aggregate([
    { $match: { createdAt: { $gte: start, $lte: end }, 'status.verified': true } },
    { 
      $group: { 
        _id: null,
        balance: {
          $sum: "$revenue"
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    }
  ], next);
```

Which suggests the error is with my conditional sum. The error thrown by MongoDB is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at redacted:10:20
    at redacted/node_modules/mongoose/lib/aggregate.js:529:13
```

My schema is

```
var schema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },

  status: {
    verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    completed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    canceled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    refused: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  },

  meta: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {} },
  revenue: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
```

Note: the `createdAt` value used in `$match` is inserted automatically by a plugin.

Comment: If I filter it, would that not cause `balance` to be a sum of `revenue` where `$user == user`, rather than a sum of `revenue` across all users?

Answer (score 2):

The **`$cond`** operator should essentially be an expression of the **`$sum`** operator, like the following:

```
this.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "createdAt": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }, 
        "status.verified": true 
    } },
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": null,
            "balance": { "$sum": "$revenue" },
            "count": {
                "$sum": { 
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$user", user ] }, 
                        1, 0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
], next);
```

Comment: Running this throws `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: Have you tried running the same aggregation pipeline in mongo shell?